# Where do I put my Hello world PHP file on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache

So I want to learn PHP, and I've installed it with "sudo apt-get install php5" on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I see it also installed Apache.

Now I've created my program, and I've saved it to a php file.

```
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

I know that I need to use something like `http://localhost/myfile.php`, but where do I put the file, so Apache will see it?

Comment: http://localhost/your_file_path/filename.php

Comment: @zerkms I am always being surprised by the document links you find - or that someone went to the trouble of actually putting that up to help folks new to php. Just amazing :)

Comment: @Fluffeh: to be honest I didn't know about that page until I put "php tutorial" into google. It was among 3 top results and overall it took 15 seconds to realize that's what OP wants.

Comment: @sashoalm: "StackOverflow is meant to be a Wikipedia of FAQs" --- not for RFTM-alike questions. Or for the question whose exact title (just try it) points to hundreds of articles. SO is meant to be a FAQ, not a duplicate for every single article over there.

Comment: Guys, take a room or get a private chat.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pick a name for it lets use `hello.php` for this example.

On Ubuntu the folder is `/var/www/html`, NOT `/var/www`. You will need root access for that. So you save the file as `/var/www/html/hello.php`.

Open up a web browser and enter the following address:

`localhost/hello.php`

And BAM. There's you page.

Comment: this works...In a tutorial it was given /var/www/info.php . Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I have done it, but the php parts of code are not executed. only the html parts are executed! what should I do?

Comment: you can change to the directory to /var/www/html location at the terminal and through sudo gedit hello.php you will be able to create php files there. which actually gives the root access to the file.

Answer (score 3):

The most voted solution didn't work for me. What I did to solve it was: searching directly in the root for the faq.html file that comes with XAMPP, and found that it was located in

> /opt/lampp/htdocs

so there is where I put my files, and it worked perfectly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The document root folder under *buntu 14.04 is /var/www/html/

The link for your browser is then: localhost/FILENAME.php

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, but this solution did not work. When i tried to call my hello.php script via

```
ip/hello.php
```

The error logs from my apache gave this message

```
[Fri Jun 26 16:21:27 2015] [:error] [pid +++] [client ip.ip.ip.ip:pppp] script '/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/hello.php' not found or unable to stat
```

When I moved the script from `/var/www/html/` to `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have php5 and apache2 installed and apache running, here's how to get to script execution quickly.

create script:

```
echo "<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>" > /var/www/index.php
```

open browser:

```
gnome-open http://localhost/index.php
# or: 
sensible-browser http://localhost/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it possible for Apache to see and play with your helloWorld.php or any other file it should be inside /var/www/html/

But /var/www/html/   requires root privilege to write or create documents here.  I.e use sudo in the terminal to open up the editor or simply extend the privilege to write and execute by using `chmod` command

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with PHP its better to install lamp server using tasksel

```
sudo apt install tasksel
```

and follow some easy steps after run it

```
tasksel
```

easy install for all modules required, after install /var/www/html is your home directory