# Debian Wheezy, php5/apache installed, but php files show as plain text

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

I installed php using `sudo apt-get install php` on Debian Wheezy. This installed Apache, and I created a file named `/var/www/index.php`.

However, when I opened in the browser `localhost/index.php`, the file showed as plain text. What's interesting is, [I had tried the same thing on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825248/where-do-i-put-my-hello-world-php-file-on-ubuntu), and it worked there out of the box, so there's some difference between Debian and Ubuntu here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you need to restart apache after installing it on Debian. So when installing php, you do this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

After that your PHP files will work fine.

Comment: I reproduced it, too. I removed apache and php5, then installed again - index.php was plain text. Then I restarted apache, and it worked. So it's reproducible.